# ABP V5.0.0-rc1 start up projects failed with error "number of args calling Redis command From Lua script"

Tags: abp

I went through the updates of [ABP V5.0.X](https://blog.abp.io/abp/ABP-IO-Platform-5.0-RC-1-Has-Been-Released) however when I run locally both projects IdentityServer and HttpApi.Host failed to start at start-up and showed following logs while database and redis-cache properly set and all connections were available.

**UI error message:**

> Tenant not found! There is no tenant with the tenant id or name:
> e1a8510c-a629-29ac-9f35-3a00858bad04

**Console logs:**

```
Initialized all ABP modules.  
[23:17:33 INF] Now listening on: https://localhost:44390
[23:17:33 INF] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.  
[23:17:33 INF] Hosting environment: Development  
[23:17:33 INF] Content root path: C:\projects\Tilde\aspnet-core\src\Tilde.IdentityServer
[23:17:33 INF] Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:44390/ - -  
[23:17:35 WRN] ERR Error running script (call to 
f_3915ee22fda531a1d5661f2523d0443fd35ff0a4): @user_script:2: @user_script: 2: Wrong 
number of args calling Redis command From Lua script
StackExchange.Redis.RedisServerException: ERR Error running script (call to 
f_3915ee22fda531a1d5661f2523d0443fd35ff0a4): @user_script:2: @user_script: 2: Wrong 
number of args calling Redis command From Lua script
at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis.RedisCache.SetAsync(String key, 
Byte[] value, DistributedCacheEntryOptions options, CancellationToken token)
at Volo.Abp.Caching.DistributedCache`2.<>c__DisplayClass51_0. 
<<SetAsync>g__SetRealCache|0>d.MoveNext()    
[23:17:35 WRN] ERR Error running script (call to 
f_3915ee22fda531a1d5661f2523d0443fd35ff0a4): @user_script:2: @user_script: 2: Wrong 
number of args calling Redis command From Lua script
StackExchange.Redis.RedisServerException: ERR Error running script (call to 
f_3915ee22fda531a1d5661f2523d0443fd35ff0a4): @user_script:2: @user_script: 2: Wrong 
number of args calling Redis command From Lua script
at Volo.Abp.Caching.StackExchangeRedis.AbpRedisCache.SetManyAsync(IEnumerable`1 items, 
DistributedCacheEntryOptions options, CancellationToken token)
at Volo.Abp.Caching.DistributedCache`2.<>c__DisplayClass54_0. 
<<SetManyAsync>g__SetRealCache|0>d.MoveNext()  
[23:17:35 WRN] ERR Error running script (call to 
f_3915ee22fda531a1d5661f2523d0443fd35ff0a4): @user_script:2: @user_script: 2: Wrong 
number of args calling Redis command From Lua script
StackExchange.Redis.RedisServerException: ERR Error running script (call to 
f_3915ee22fda531a1d5661f2523d0443fd35ff0a4): @user_script:2: @user_script: 2: Wrong 
number of args calling Redis command From Lua script
at Volo.Abp.Caching.StackExchangeRedis.AbpRedisCache.SetManyAsync(IEnumerable`1 items, 
DistributedCacheEntryOptions options, CancellationToken token)
```

**Package references:**

```
   <ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI" Version="6.0.1-rc2.4" />
<PackageReference Include="AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI.Client" Version="6.0.1-rc2.4" />
<PackageReference Include="AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI.InMemory.Storage" Version="6.0.1-rc2.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="4.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Async" Version="1.5.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.StackExchangeRedis" Version="6.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google" Version="6.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount" Version="6.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter" Version="6.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.MultiTenancy" Version="5.0.0-rc.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Volo.Abp.Autofac" Version="5.0.0-rc.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Serilog" Version="5.0.0-rc.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Volo.Abp.Identity.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0-rc.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Volo.Abp.Caching.StackExchangeRedis" Version="5.0.0-rc.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Volo.Abp.Swashbuckle" Version="5.0.0-rc.1" />
```

redis-cache screenshot after flush:
[image]

Comment: Did you clear your Redis cache and then try to run both projects?

Comment: Yes @EngincanVeske, still same issue

Comment: @EngincanVeske, is there any way to disable cache for those projects? 
Or is there any way to add redis flush to module startup in csharp?

Comment: @EngincanVeske, added redis-cache-log. any idea? can you please ask halilibrahimkalkan?

Comment: You can disable the Redis cache, see https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/5.0/Redis-Cache#configuration.

Comment: @EngincanVeske, this issue is not about the cache. after I tested. abp.tenant library is broken

Comment: @EngincanVeske, this issue is not about the cache. after I tested abp.tenant library with mongodb is broken even with stable version before

Answer (score 1):

it's related to your browser cookies.
you have an invalid tenantId in your browser cache related to your previous ABP project (probably you created it for testing). therefore it cannot find this tenantId.  clear your browser cookies